# Updating user profile with Nuxt js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to update my user Profile but am not getting the request which was sent to Laravel from Nuxt.

What did I do wrong here?

Here is UpdateProfile.vue

```
 <v-form v-model="valid">
        
        <v-text-field v-model="currentUser.name"
                        label="Name"
                        :rules="[required('name')]"
                        v-if="hasName"/>

        <!-- HIDDEN INPUT -->
        <input type="file" id="file" @change="handleFileUpload($event)" />

        <v-text-field v-model="currentUser.email"
                        label="Email"
                        :rules="[required('email'), emailFormat()]" />
        
        <v-text-field v-model="currentUser.password"
                        label="Password"
                        :type="showPassword ?  'text' : 'password'"
                        :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                        @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                        counter=true
                        :rules="[required('password'), minLength('password',5)]"/>
        
        <v-text-field v-model="currentUser.password_confirmation"
                        label="Password Confirmation"
                        :type="showPassword ?  'text' : 'password'"
                        :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                        @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                        counter=true
                        :rules="[required('password_confirmation'), minLength('password_confirmation',5)]"
                         v-if="confirm_password"/>

        <v-btn @click="submitForm(currentUser)" :disabled="!valid"> {{buttonText}}</v-btn>
```

Here is the Methods

```
<script>
import validations from '@/store/utils/validations'
    export default {
      
        data(){
             console.log(validations);
            return {
                valid:false,
                showPassword:false,
                hasName:false,
                confirm_password:false,
                file:'',
                currentUser:{
                    name:'',
                    email:'',
                    password:'',
                },
                ...validations
            }
        },
        
        props:[
            "buttonText",
            "submitForm",
            "hasName",
            "confirm_password",
            "currentUser",
            "handleFileUpload"
            ]
    }
</script>
```

Here is Profile.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
     <v-container>
        <h1>UPDATE PROFILE</h1>
        
        <UpdateProfile :currentUser="currentUser" :submitForm="updateProfile" buttonText="Update" :handleFileUpload="handleFileUpload" hasName="true" confirm_password="true" />
    
         
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the Methods

```
<script>
    export default {

    //     // COMPUTED START HERE
       computed:{
            // ...mapState('videos',['currentVideos']),
            currentUser(){
               return this.$auth.user || {};
            },

        },
         methods:{
          
           async updateProfile(currentUser){
            
             

                         

                  let formData = new FormData();
                  formData.append('files', this.file);
                  formData.append('currentUser',JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
                  formData.append('_method', 'PATCH');

                  try {
                   await this.$axios.patch(`/profile/${this.currentUser.id}`, formData, {  header:{"content-type":"multipart/form-data"}}
                    )

                   
                  } catch (e) {
                    this.error = 'Something error found !';
                  }
                
             
        },

         handleFileUpload(event){
           console.log(event);
             this.file = event.target.files[0];
           }
    },
   
    }
</script>
```

Laravel Backend |
API

```
Route::patch('/profile/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'update']); 

``
On The ProfilesController.php
```

````
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
{


     return  response()->json(['message'=> $request->all()]);
}
```
````

And yet the request was sent but the response is empty[image: Here is the request image]
[image: Here is the response which came back empty from but a request was sent successful]

Comment: If the request was properly sent from what you see in the network tab, the next step is to double check in your backend database.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your response sir.
 I used Laravel on the backend but i can't get the request which was sent from nuxt but am getting a empty response on the backend laravel.
Pls what will i do?